# What does @:keep mean in Haxe?

Tags: haxe

I am new to Haxe and playing with the [OpenFL Starling Sample](https://github.com/openfl/starling/tree/v1.8/samples/demo) code - 
I noticed a **`@:keep`** metadata before the class declaration. What does it mean?

```
@:keep class TouchScene extends Scene {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haxe allows metadata tags on classes and functions.

`@:keep` is a metadata tag that instructs the compiler's [dead code elimination](https://haxe.org/manual/cr-dce.html) feature not to remove the class or function, even if it believes that the class or function is unused.

There are many other [built-in metadata tags](https://haxe.org/manual/cr-metadata.html).

FYI, for advanced users, you can create schemas and specify your own metadata tags (and parse them using macros). For example, my [lazy-props library](https://github.com/jcward/lazy-props#supported-metadata-tags) does exactly this.

Comment: for what reason need compiler eliminate dead code? how it knows need I code or not? I didn't get it.

Comment: @VakhtangiBeridze it's a compiler optimization available in many compilers. Read all about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination Obviously there are pros and cons, and metatags like `@:keep` allow us control over the feature.

Comment: @VakhtangiBeridze Oh, and the compiler knows whether you need code or not by tracking the usage of classes, functions, variables, etc. It's especially useful for large libraries, where you may only need a subset of the features for your app. The compiler removes all the code that's unnecessary for your app to function.